# Do all Time Lords go to the Academy, and what do they do afterwards?

Tags: doctor-who

Do all Time Lords go to the academy? If not all go the academy, then how are the Time lords selected to go the academy?

And after "graduating" from the academy, what do the Time Lords become — scholars, soldiers or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hardly anything is known about the Academy.

It's been seen or mentioned on-screen only two or three times in all of *Doctor Who* history (the count may vary depending on how liberal one is on interpreting certain off-handed references). Here's what's known that's relevant to your question:

In *The Sound of Drums* we are told that it's a kind of boarding school for Time Lord children. It sounds like the testing process isn't merit-based: if you're a Time Lord kid you're in.

In *The Ribos Operation* we learn that graduation involves a test which can be taken multiple times.

[A bit more is told us about the Academy](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Lord_Academy) in non-TV sources (audio stories, novels, comics), but nothing really relevant to what you're asking. Non-TV sources are dubious canon, most commonly treated as "canon unless/until the TV show itself contradicts them." For example, the novel *Lungbarrow* tells us that Time Lords are never children--they're "made," not born, because Time Lords have been sterile for millenia. *The Sound of Drums* ignores that completely by showing us Time Lords as children being inducted into the Academy.

Comment: Confirmation of the existence of Time Lord Children is also in the 50th anniversary episode with discussion of Time Lord Children deaths in the destruction of Gallifrey.